# Reset depth on Kendo datepicker

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datepicker

My client has requested that our Kendo DatePicker reset to the original view depth each time the calendar is opened.

Example: the calendar is set to start at "year" view and the user exits from "century" view without choosing a date. The next time the calendar opens it is back at "year" view rather than still being stuck on "century".

After digging through the api this function doesn't seem to be readily exposed.

Has anyone managed to do something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in such a luxurious position of power :/

Comment: Then go to the person who is and make them pop the why stack. If they can't - have them do the same w the client. Client's aren't always right (and they might appreciate you trying to save them time/money). Don't let them waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same issue and found a solution.

You can call `setOptions` and pass the options you want to set, such as the depth or start. This will reset the depth allowing you to reset the depth when the calendar is opened.  I've added that call to the close event so that it'll occur each time the calendar is closed.

**[Dojo Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/Iwepi/3)**

```
  var kendoOptions = {
    depth: "year",
    start: "year"
  };
  $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker(kendoOptions);

  var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
  datepicker.bind('close', function() {
    // add if statement for scenearios where you want to reset the depth
    this.setOptions(kendoOptions);
  });
```